# Pulling data from multiple pdf forms, into workable format for PBI/PQ?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, pdf-form

I have a set of completed pdf forms from which I need to extract the data and generate some analysis.

I have used acrobat's "merge to excel" function, which results in a single sheet with a row for each question and a separate column of responses for each file.

This format has proven difficult to analyse, so in the past I've manually moved the data around so all the responses are in a single column, in order to be able to graph it / chuck into a pivot table, etc.

[image: before and after tables]

*Image description: example demonstrating how data looks when merged from pdf (table A) and also how it looks after I've manually reformatted it (table B).*

Now, this isn't a particularly elegant solution, but it has worked ok for our purposes to date. However, our volume of data is about to increase from half a dozen files to around 100, so I really don't want to be dealing with having to reformat data manually in that volume.

I know I could throw some VBA at the situation to automate reformatting the data, however I feel like this shouldn't be necessary at all - that I *ought* to be able to work with the data in its existing format using power query... however I just can't figure out how to make this work.

Can anyone please explain to me how to get data from table A in a way that can be used in PBI (or power pivot)? Or point me to any useful resources if this is well documented somewhere I've not managed to google my own way towards...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Having mixed data type columns tends to be hard to work with. Depending on various factors, it might be preferable to transpose the table so that separate questions are on separate columns. (Just a thought. Might not be the best approach for your case.)

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into powerquery [Data ... from table source]

Right click first column and Unpivot other columns

Rename columns as appropriate, sort, rearrange columns, etc

File ... close and load to ...

The only issue might be formatting of the date column since the values column would be a mixed type

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Column1", "Question"}, {"Attribute", "Location"}, {"Value", "Response"}})
in  #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: did that work for you?